# Where are additional <Build Dependecies>/<Project Dependecies> stored in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've added an additional project dependency like this: Project>Right Click>Build Dependencies>Project Dependencies

[image]

I know that visual studio saves some information about project settings in the user-project file (.csproj.user). But I wanted to make sure all my colleagues also have this dependency added. So I started looking for changes in git (none), then changes in the .user-file, also none. I'm wondering, where is this information stored?

Any Ideas?

Comment: It is saved in the file that knows what projects are around, the .sln solution file.  "ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies)" element.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes you're right. I had to save the solution file first, that's why I had no changes in git. Thanks! Please add this as an answer so I can checkmark it!